# How do I configure multiple VLAN connections on a single NIC?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I know how to add the extra IPs for the additional VLANs on the single NIC, but I'm not sure how to go about directing the traffic to the separate VLANs.

On the Windows level is there anything I need to do besides enable tagging on the NIC?

On the switch side I'm guessing I just need to add multiple VLANs to the port the NIC is connected to and the tagging will determine which VLAN the traffic goes to.

Is there anything else I need to setup?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like just about everything you need to do. On the windows side of things, go to the properties of your nic and hit the configure button next to your nic's name. there should be a tab (assuming intel or broadcom) that says VLAN. Add the vlans you want, and individual nics will appear in the network connections. 
On the switch side (assuming cisco), in the interface configuration mode, use:

```
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 5,15,101,900
 switchport mode trunk
```

would obviously be if you wanted 4 separate interfaces, one for each of the vlans listed above.

Comment: I'm using the HP Network Configuration Utility. Where is an option for each network team that say VLAN (802.1Q) where I can add this...any idea if there is anywhere else I need to add this? I don't see the tagging option anywhere.

Comment: Read the documentation for the HP Network Configuration Utility.

Comment: @matt: Since you mention Broadcom, the correct procedure to use BACS to add additional tagged interfaces. They show up as separate network connections in the usual place. Most other brands ought to be similar.

Comment: May have come in handy... about 375 days ago.